# TikZ Corners Missing

Tags: tikz-pgf

Questions:

1. Why are the top corners of this number line missing?
2. Why aren't the bottom corners or any other corners of this number line missing?
3. How do I ensure the corners are always there?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.08cm]

\draw (0,0)--(5,0);
\draw (0,0.3)--(5,0.3);

\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 {
 \node at (\x,-0.55) {\x};
 \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,0.3);
 }

\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 \draw (\x,0)--(\x,0.3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That code yields this:

[image]

Comment: Also, I am unable to get the code in this post to format as it is supposed to. Don't know why.

Comment: The code was interpreted as part of the list (it then need 8 spaces). I added an (invisible) HTML comment, to fix this.

Comment: What's a better way for me to tell the list to end?

Comment: I fear there’s none in markdown … (regarding your actual problem I’m posting an answer soon)

Comment: Just for reference about the Markdown-problem: [Code block is not properly formatted when placed immediately after a list item](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3327) A comment as Tobi added is the usual way of fixing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that the lines end at a certain point – exactly at this point. have a look at this image (MWE below):

[image: first image]

The black dot marks (0,0). Both lines are drawn to (0,0) and because of the heavy line width it seems that the corner between them is missing, while actually the lines are exactly as specified: ending in (0,0).

However there are some ways to get a corner:

1. make *one* path going through (0,0) having a real corner there
2. use `line cap = rect` to add a little extra bit at the end of each line, so the overlap of the red an blue line form a corner (affects both ends!).
3. lengthen the path by half the amount of the line width with `shorten < = 0.5\pgflinewidth` (affects only the end specified by using either `shorten <` = start or `shorten >` = end)

1 to 3 from left to right:

[image: alternatives]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = 4mm]
   \draw [red] (0,-2) -- (0,0);
   \draw [blue] (2,0) -- (0,0);
   \fill (0,0) circle [radius = 1pt];
   \begin{scope}[xshift=25mm]% solution 1
      \draw [red] (0,-2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
      \fill (0,0) circle [radius = 1pt];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[xshift=50mm]% solution 2
      \draw [red,  line cap=rect] (0,-2) -- (0,0);
      \draw [blue] (2,0) -- (0,0);
      \fill (0,0) circle [radius = 1pt];
   \end{scope}
   \begin{scope}[xshift=75mm]% solution 3
   \draw [red, shorten > = -0.5\pgflinewidth] (0,-2) -- (0,0);
   \draw [blue] (2,0) -- (0,0);
   \fill (0,0) circle [radius = 1pt];
   \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

For your code I’d use version 1 and add little vertical pieces to the horizontal line:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.08cm]
\draw (0,0) -- (5,0);
\draw (0,0.2) -- (0,0.3) -- (5,0.3) -- (5,0.2);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 {
  \node at (\x,-0.55) {\x};
  \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,0.3);
 }
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 \draw (\x,0)--(\x,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```