# Drawing a semicircle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I draw a semicircle in `TikZ`?  `A` and `B` are the endpoints of its diameter, and I have two other points specified.  I have a command that is not able to be compiled.  I put a "%" in front of it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}




\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

%A semicircle is drawn.
\path (-1.5,0) coordinate (A) (1.5,0) coordinate (B) (60:1.5) coordinate (C) (120:1.5) coordinate (D);
%\draw (A) -- (B) arc (C) arc (D) arc (A) -- cycle;

%Labels for the vertices are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=240, inner sep=0] at ($(C) +(60:0.15)$){$C$};
\node[anchor=300, inner sep=0] at ($(D) +(120:0.15)$){$D$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15972/whats-the-easiest-way-to-draw-the-arc-defined-by-three-points-in-tikz The semicircle is easy. The hard or tedious part is finding start and end angles. For such, tkz-euclide gives really handy macros.

Comment: @percusse  All the codes at this website involve a lot of code for just drawing a semicircle.  And I am not familiar with `pgfmathsetmacro` and `\newcommand`.

Comment: @percusse I know that I can draw the semicircle with the commands and `\draw(A) -- (B);` and `\draw (1.5,0) arc (0:180:1.5);`.  I thought it would be nice to have one command for it.

Comment: as i said drawing is the easy part you need the angles and the radius. That's why they go through the hoops

Comment: You can always make a node if you really want a simple semicircle-maker. `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} ... \node [semicircle] {}; ...`.

Comment: A semicircle is a special case of an arc. Drawing arcs is explained in Section 2.10 of the TikZ/pgf manual.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since all coordinates are known, it's possible to draw a `circle` with defined radius into a clipping rectangle. The result is a semicircle. After that, only base and labels should be added.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

% A clipped circle is drawn
\begin{scope}
    \clip (-1.5,0) rectangle (1.5,1.5);
    \draw (0,0) circle(1.5);
    \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\end{scope}
%
%%Labels for the vertices are typeset.
\node[below left= 1mm of {(-1.5,0)}] {$A$};
\node[below right= 1mm of {(1.5,0)}] {$B$};
\node[above right= 1mm of {(60:1.5)}] {$C$};
\node[above left= 1mm of {(120:1.5)}] {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update:*

To avoid the problems that Tobi mention in his comment, for this particular case is easy to write:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]

\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0) arc(0:180:1.5) --cycle;
%
%%Labels for the vertices are typeset.
\node[below left= 1mm of {(-1.5,0)}] {$A$};
\node[below right= 1mm of {(1.5,0)}] {$B$};
\node[above right= 1mm of {(60:1.5)}] {$C$};
\node[above left= 1mm of {(120:1.5)}] {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now the semicircle can be filled without problems and exist connections between base and arc as can be seen in following detail.

[image]

Comment: But in that case half of the line width in the left and right part of the circle gets cropped too and furthermore there is [no connection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327446/4918) between the base and the arc.

Comment: @Tobi. You're right. I hope the second solution solves both problems.

Comment: @Ignasi  Yes, that is the simple command that I wanted.  Instead of typing `--` as I would for drawing a line segment between two points, I type `arc` to indicate that I want a circular path from the point before `arc` to the point after `arc`.

Comment: @Tobi  Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am sure that I will use the option `fill` in a draw command to fill a circular sector.

Answer (score 11):

Since the semicircle is not rotated and the radius is known, the drawing can be done without explicit calculations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
  % Define coordinates
  \def\Radius{1.5}
  \path
    (-\Radius, 0) coordinate (A)
    -- coordinate (M)
    (\Radius, 0) coordinate (B)
    (M) +(60:\Radius) coordinate (C)
    +(120:\Radius) coordinate (D)
  ;
  % Draw semicircle
  \draw
    (B) arc(0:180:\Radius) -- cycle
  ;
  % Annotations
  \path[inner sep=0pt]
    (A) node[below=.3333em] {$A$}
    (B) node[below=.3333em] {$B$}
    (C) node[above right=.2em] {$C$}
    (D) node[above left=.2em] {$D$}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]