# Semicircle from a circle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, path-clipping

Referring to the `\clip` answer in [Drawing a semicircle in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330580/drawing-a-semicircle-in-tikz), I wanted to draw a semicircle. But the approach doesn't work here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:D] (D) at ($(A)!.5!(C)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:E] (E) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);

  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
  \draw (D) let \p1 = ($(C) - (D)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
  \clip (A) rectangle (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, when using relative points like `C`, `D` and `E`, how to determine the end point of the rectangle while clipping in `\clip (A) rectangle (8,8);`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to draw a semicircle, why not to use an `arc`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:D] (D) at ($(A)!.5!(C)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:E] (E) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);

  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
  \draw (A) let \p1 = ($(C) - (D)$), \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=\n1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put `\clip` before the things to be clipped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:D] (D) at ($(A)!.5!(C)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:E] (E) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);
  \clip (A) rectangle (8,8);

  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
  \draw (D) let \p1 = ($(C) - (D)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you also help with the second query.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, put the clip inside a scope for safety.

As for the clipping rectangle, obviously (A) is one corner and the other corner should be high enough without adding space to the image (bounding box).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (8,0);
  \coordinate[label=above:C] (C) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:D] (D) at ($(A)!.5!(C)$);
  \coordinate[label=above:E] (E) at ($(B)!.5!(C)$);
  \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B);
  \path (D) let \p1 = ($(C) - (D)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});% set bounding box
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (A) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \draw (D) let \p1 = ($(C) - (D)$) in circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```